# The type timestmap of mysql

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE test SET add_time = '2017-04-29' WHERE id = 1;
```

The type of 'add_time' is timestmap,the above statement will be inserted '2017-04-29 15:00:00',my question is why it is not '2017-04-29 00:00:00'.It may be related to the time zone of mysql?

Comment: Yes, it's because of the time zone.

Comment: How to set up to get `2017-04-29 00:00:00`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `MySQL 5` and above, `TIMESTAMP` values are converted from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and converted back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. (This occurs only for the TIMESTAMP data type, and not for other types such as DATETIME.)

By default, the current time zone for each connection is the server's time. The time zone can be set on a per-connection basis, as described in *[MySQL Server Time Zone Support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//time-zone-support.html)*.

`2017-04-29 15:00:00` means that its a time of 3 PM, 29th April, 2017. `Timestamp` saves date and time as well. And that time is because of the time zone.

However if you need to select datepart only, you can do the following:

```
SELECT date(ColumnName) from tablename
```

The above will get only the date part only.

> The DATETIME type is used when you need values that contain both date
>   and time information. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in
>   'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01
>   00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.
>
> ...
>
> The TIMESTAMP data type has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to
>   '2038-01-09 03:14:07' UTC. It has varying properties, depending on the
>   MySQL version and the SQL mode the server is running in.

For your situation, I will suggest you to use `datetime` instead of `timestamp`

Comment: Why is it setting the time to 15:00 when he leaves out the time?

Comment: `2017-04-29` was inserted in `Timestamp`,why it save `2017-04-29 15:00:00` not for `2017-04-29 15:00:00`?

Comment: This is because of mysql time zone. please see my updated answer

Comment: Can i set `system_time_zone` or `time_zone` to make it `2017-04-29 00:00:00`?

Comment: Thank,I just want to know why this is so.For my question,i insert `2017-04-29 00:00:00` into the `Timestamp`,lol.